# How to manage UIButton click sound iOS

Tags: ios, audio, ios7, uibutton

I am using the following code to get a sound on button click.And it works perfect. The problem is this sound is not getting reduced if i reduce the volume on the phone. I want to manage button click sound as per the volume button. I am not using input view.

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef) CFBridgingRetain(soundUrl) , &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Comment: The above code is written inside method for button clicked

Answer (score 1):

As Duncan C suggests, try AVAudioPlayer:

1. Import `AVFoundation.framework`.
2. Replace your code snippet with:

   ```
   NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

   AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
   [player play];
   ```

Comment: i tried this,but getting an error No visible  @ interface for AVAudioplayer declares the selector initwithurl.

Comment: I cleared this error ,but no sound is getting played.It is not initwithurl,it is initwithcontentsofurl.

Comment: @suraj can you please tell me how did you remove this error -No visible @ interface for AVAudioplayer declares the selector initwithurl.

Comment: @Nitesh check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878257/no-visible-interface-for-avaudioplayer-declares-the-selector-initwithurl

Comment: Sorry for the late response/correction, was offline for a while. Suraj, are you still unable to hear the sound?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to create an AVAudioPlayer for my button sound and play that. AVAudioPlayer honors the system volume.

I've created a separate IBAction method that plays the sound, and then I link my buttons to both actions. That way it's easy to turn the sound on and off simply by linking the action. If you always want sounds to play then you might want to put a call to a sound play method directly in your IBAction methods.

Answer (score -1):

Check [Click here](http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/making-ios-app-with-sound-play-on-each-button-click/) that might help you.