# No Visible interface for 'AVAudioPlayer declares the selector initWithUrl:'

Tags: ios, audio, uibutton, avfoundation

I am trying to play a button click sound,also that i should be able to manage click sound along with volume button.

What i have done is 
 Added AVFoundationFramework to project,

in .h file

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

in .m file under button click method

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithURL:soundUrl];

[player play];
```

but i get the above error.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ["`initWithContentsOfURL:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL%3aerror%3a) not "`initWithURL:`".

As in:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                          initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl];
```

Comment: Thanks bro.Error is removed.Problem is sound is not getting played.Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, check to see if you really have the correct URL by using "`[soundURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError: &error]`" before you play the sound.  [There's more information about making certain you have the right URL in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927754/testing-file-existence-using-nsurl).